# Deploy 2 Github repositories to the same Heroku app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have:

1. A client GitHub repository (html, JS & CSS files) - contains client directory.
2. BackEnd Github Repository (Node.JS) - contains server directory, package.json, server.js.

Is it possible to setup deployment of those 2 repositories on the same Heroku Domain - So I'll have there the following structure?

- client
- server
- server.js
- package.json

Comment: What about creating 3rd project and there in package.json as a dependency just add client and server?

Comment: What do you mean by saying dependency?

Comment: Maybe this link offers some insight?  It looks like they group the two applications into a single repo and deploy it like that.
:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461517/deploy-two-separate-heroku-apps-from-same-git-repo

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Thanks, Its seems it a different case - I'm look for deploying 2 Repositories to the same Heroku app

Comment: @LeonidLazaryev Thanks, There is no real dependency between those 2 - I just want to be able to deploy each part separately - I know this use case exist but I'm not sure Heroku support that.

Answer (score 0):

The interface of Heroku doesn't allow you to connect more than one GitHub repository explicitly.
I think the best possibility is to use Docker images
https://www.heroku.com/deploy-with-docker

You can create a separate repository for the image and create webhooks on a push event to your client and server repositories.