# Nodejs: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myproject.git'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, heroku

I made a portfolio with Reactjs and a little bit of nodejs to implement nodemailer, and now I'm trying to deploy to heroku but I'm getting this error: ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dedaportfolio.git

I'm trying everthing but it seems nothing working, I did a lot of research around but nothing worked to me
Here is the error when I'm trying to push to heroku

```
    Enumerating objects: 38099, done.
Counting objects: 100% (38099/38099), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (28232/28232), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38099/38099), 98.10 MiB | 108.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 38099 (delta 8542), reused 38081 (delta 8535), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.15.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   7.24.2
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.15.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.15.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 7.24.2 (replacing 8.5.5)...
remote:        npm 7.24.2 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        added 89 packages, and audited 90 packages in 8s
remote:
remote:        12 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        1 critical severity vulnerability
remote:
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > myportfolio@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build
remote:
remote:        
remote:        up to date, audited 1466 packages in 3s
remote:
remote:        194 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        7 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:        To address issues that do not require attention, run:
remote:          npm audit fix
remote:
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        added 64 packages, removed 188 packages, changed 281 packages, and audited 1342 packages in 27s
remote:
remote:        207 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        6 high severity vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:        To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
remote:          npm audit fix --force
remote:
remote:        Run `npm audit` for details.
remote:        
remote:        > frontend@0.1.0 build
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:
remote: sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to dedaportfolio.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/dedaportfolio.git
 ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dedaportfolio.git'
```

this the package.json in the root of my project

```
{
  "name": "myportfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.15.0",
    "npm":"7.24.2"
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "dev":"concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```

This is my client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.15.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your `client/package.json` to your question.

Comment: i have never tried to use single repo or heroku server to run/deploy both node & react on single server. Usually i would split it in 2 repositories/servers. Or have only backend to render with templating engines. But i read there is a way to try what you are trying - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997828/heroku-how-to-deploy-a-node-app-with-client-and-server-running-on-different-por

Comment: @Chris, there it is

Answer (score 0):

The final three messages here:

> ```
> To https://git.heroku.com/dedaportfolio.git
>  ! [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dedaportfolio.git'
> ```

are from Git itself and are simply a *summary* of the fact that Heroku (not Git) didn't like your code.  Ignore them entirely as they add no information whatsoever; pay attention *only* to the `remote:`-prefixed lines.  Git relays these lines to you whenever Heroku tells you *why* it does not like your code.

The remaining problems are all specific to either Heroku or your code.  In this case, the errors come from `npm`, which is noting:

> high severity vulnerabilities

which you should fix because [security vulnerabilities are bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)), but most importantly, from the next step in the build process:

> ```
> sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
> ```

which simply means that your `react-scripts` in the stuff you're deploying is wrong, so have a look at that.

Comment: I got your point, but how can I do that? I'm stuck at this for 2 days

Comment: Check the permissions on your `react-scripts` file, and check to see if it starts with something that would make it executable (e.g., `#! /bin/sh` or whatever interpreter is supposed to run it).