# Failed build on Heroku with custom heroku-postbuild script

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I have two main folders for my project: `server` and `client`. Heroku only seems to care about the `server/package.json`. Deployment is going fine until it returns an error when the process runs the `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"` command from `package.json`.

Here's the error message from the console:

```
-----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild
remote:        > npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:        
remote: npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote: npm ERR! syscall open
remote: npm ERR! path /tmp/build_25b1f86c/client/package.json
remote: npm ERR! errno -2
remote: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_25b1f86c/client/package.json'
remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote: npm ERR! enoent 
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3i4hV/_logs/2022-08-05T15_34_56_961Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
```

Here's `server/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.16.0",
    "npm": "8.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "passport": "^0.5.3",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "stripe": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's `client/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried removing parts of `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"` to shorten it into `"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false"` in other deployments and it worked. It seems `"npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"` is the part not working in the `heroku-postbuild` script.

Would you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git (see [the top of my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73252857/1256452) for more about that). What's going on is that `client/package.json` is missing. Whether it's *really* supposed to exist, I have no idea, but something in your code says that it is supposed to exist, and it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @torek for your help! I have, indeed, a client/package.json file, which exists. I edited the original post to include it. In that architecture, the `client` folder is within the `server` folder. Reading your answer, I still couldn't make it work. Would you have another option to explore?

Comment: Huh, that part looks OK - at this point you need an npm and/or node.js expert.

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know! I'll keep digging. Still haven't fixed it for now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it. My course TA helped me figure it out. The solution below worked.

In my Github repo called `server`, the `client` directory was completely missing, so, the Heroku server was likely having the same problem. And it did. I had to delete the `.git` directory in the client so version control doesn't think this is a submodule. From the root repository:

```
cd client

rm -r .git

git rm --cached .

cd ..

git add client

git commit -m "remove submodule"

git push origin main

git push heroku main
```