# Create one heroku app from two git repositories

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, heroku, react-redux

**my issue:** I have server written using Spring Boot, Spring Data, MongoDB and postgreSQL. My client is written with React/Redux. I keep them in two separated git repos. Now I’d like to deploy them to Heroku. I already deployed back end but now I’m not sure how to add frontend. I’d prefer to have it as one app because then I wouldn’t have to worty about csrf.

**what solutions I was thinking about:** As far as I’m concerned I see two solutions: 
1) deploying front end as a separated app and make calls to backend (already deployed app) 
2) somehow making it into one app. I read a couple of solutions and one suggested making a Procfile, but in that question there was one git repo. [Deploy two separate heroku apps from same git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461517/deploy-two-separate-heroku-apps-from-same-git-repo/41466169#41466169)

I’m using Maven and Yarn.

Answer (score 0):

If your client project is also a maven project, you can make it a dependency of your server project.

You can then make the build copy your client artifact into the src/main/resources/static folder and have your server application serve the client as static content.

Update: This link is a good guide how to do it: https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/

It describes a multi module maven project with a spring rest backend- and an angularjs frontend module. But I am certain that the principle will work also with a react/redux frontend in a separate project.

It will require some tweaking though:)

Comment: I realise now that this is not really an answer to your question. But it is a way to do it - only not the way you ask about:)